# Как послать POST запрос в Android используя не deprecated методы?

Tags: php, java, android, post

Собственно весь запрос поместился в заголовке, но для болей наглядности приведу [пример](http://www.cyberforum.ru/android-dev/thread1022607.html), как НЕ НУЖНО делать POST запросы в данный момент, т.к. все методы deprecated

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/all/index.php");

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", "andro"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text", "Привет!"));
try {
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

     e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}

$mylogin = $_POST['login'];
if($mylogin != null)
{
     $fp = fopen("counter.txt", "a"); 
     $test = fwrite($fp, $mylogin);
}
```

Comment: В чем вопрос то? Если хотите поделится решением проблемы - сначала создайте вопрос с описанием проблемы, затем подготовте ответ с ее решением и разметите его, собственно ответом.

Comment: Человек ниже всё понял, видимо вы не заметили ссылку в вопросе

Comment: @BORSHEVIK: дело в том, что ссылки не должно быть в вопросе, а должен быть весь код, необходимый для понимания задачи. Ссылка завтра сломается и весь вопрос станет бессмысленным.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используй HttpURLConnection

```
HashMap<String, String> postDataParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
postDataParams.put("some_param","1");

URL url;
    String response = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(requestURL);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);


        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                response+=line;
            }
        }
        else {
            response="";

            throw new HttpException(responseCode+"");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, что если у меня есть параметры для передачи, то мне их нужно добавлять методом put() в postDataParams? А ответ от сервера будет содержаться в Response?

Comment: Да postDataParams это параметры, а response  ответ сервера, вот полезные ссылки - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767952/how-to-add-parameters-to-httpurlconnection-using-post - http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: Спасибо большое, ваш ответ был дельным и правильным

Comment: @donearh, да вы телепат ;-)