# POST Запросы Android

Tags: php, java, android, post

Здравствуйте! Делал по аналогии с *AJAX* запросами (делал в свое время с помощью *jQuery*). *PHP* обработчик на стороне сервера выполняет функцию посредника между клиентом и БД. Теста ради хочу проверить что возвращает запрос к нему следующим образом:

Класс `HttpRequestProvider`

```
package ru.alexfirebreath.emberblastmanagement;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class HttpRequestProvider {
String url = "";

public HttpRequestProvider(String urlGet){
    url = urlGet;
}

public String sendPost(String args) throws Exception {

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    con.setRequestMethod("POST");

    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(args);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    // String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    in.close();

    return response.toString();


}


}
```

Соответственно в `MainActivity` на нажатие кнопки создаем строковую переменную и сохраняем в нее значение, возвращаемое sendPost и присваиваем ее значение текстовому полю

В PHP-обработчике (теста ради на данный момент) возвращается строка через банальное `echo`

В результате текстовое поле получает... ничего. Запрос формируется, но в итоге строковая пуста.

В чем ошибка?

Посмотрел предложенный пример отсюда - [Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/446896/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-post-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B2-android-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5-deprecated-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B)

Да, я забыл заносить данные в responce. Немного переделал код (включая использование HashMap для хранения параметров). Теперь он в принципе не срабатывает по нажатию кнопки. Проверил методом getPostParameterString - строка формируется корректно

```
public class HttpRequestProvider {

HashMap<String, String> postDataParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
String response = "";

String url = "";

public HttpRequestProvider(String urlGet){
    url = urlGet;
}

public void refreshParams(){
    postDataParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
}

public void setParams(String key, String value) {
    postDataParams.put(key, value);
}

public String sendPost() throws Exception {

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    con.setRequestMethod("POST");

    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(true);

    OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();

    BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8")
    );
    wr.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
    os.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        String line;
        BufferedReader re = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = re.readLine()) != null) {
            response+=line;
        }
    }
    else {
        response = "Не удалось";
    }

    return response;


}

private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws
        UnsupportedEncodingException {

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;


    if (first)
        first = false;
    else
        result.append("&");

    for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : params.entrySet()){
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(),"UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(),"UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}

public String getPostParameterString() throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    return getPostDataString(postDataParams);
}


}
```

UPD. Частично протестировал. Вылет происходит до объявления OutputStream. Попробовал реализовать это все вне класса, прямо в событии нажатия кнопки - результат тот же, любое обращение к con по какой-то неведомой причине не работает. При попытке обратиться к getMessage исключения в блоке catch приложение вылетает с ошибкой

Comment: Но так у вас же в `response ` ничего не кладётся... Он пустой...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как послать POST запрос в Android используя не deprecated методы?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/446896/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-post-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b2-android-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5-deprecated-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8b)

Comment: Исправил, однако по прежнему результат не радует

Comment: Ваш новый класс работает (`sendPost` возвращает строку с ответом), проверял на http://httpbin.org, проблема, скорее всего, в другом месте. Добавьте вывод через `Log` или в отладочном режиме по шагам пройдите.

Comment: Частично протестировал. Вылет происходит до объявления OutputStream. Попробовал реализовать это все вне класса, прямо в событии нажатия кнопки - результат тот же, любое обращение к con по какой-то неведомой причине не работает. При попытке обратиться к getMessage исключения в блоке catch приложение вылетает с ошибкой